# Expo react native app not fetching data from the backend properly

Tags: react-native, chatbot, expo-go

I am working on a event planning react native app which has a chatbot in it. The chatbot is coded in python and api calling is done in my react native app. The api is working properly i have checked it in postman. I tried running the app on expo go and on every question i ask the chatbot the reply is always "Something went wrong" , But when i tried running the app on web it is working without any problem.
The code for the chatbot:

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'; 
import Constants from "expo-constants";
const uri = Constants?.expoConfig?.hostUri
  ? Constants.expoConfig.hostUri.split(`:`).shift().concat(`:5000`)
  : `http://127.0.0.1:5000/chats`;

const Chatbot = () => {
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
  // {
  // question: "",
  // answer: "",
  // } array of this object
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState('');
 
  const handleSendMessage = async () => {
    // Send the user's message to the Flask API
    const uniqueId = uuidv4();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          question: question
        }),
      });
      
      console.log(response)
     
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setChats([...chats, data]);
      } else {
        // Handle errors, e.g., show an error message
       
        const error = { question, answer: 'Something went wrong', id: uniqueId };
        setChats([...chats, error])
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle errors, e.g., show an error message
      
      const error = { question, answer: 'Something went wrong', id: uniqueId };
      setChats([...chats, error])
    }

    setQuestion('');
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        style={{ flex: 1, padding: 16 }}
      >
        {chats.map((chat) => (
         
          <React.Fragment key={chat.id}>
            {chat.question && (
            <View
              
              style={{
                alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF',
                borderRadius: 8,
                padding: 8,
                margin: 4,
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>
                {chat.question}
              </Text>
            </View>
            )}
            {chat.answer && (
            <View
              
              style={{
                alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
                borderRadius: 8,
                padding: 8,
                margin: 4,
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>
                {chat.answer}
              </Text>
            </View>
            )}
            </React.Fragment>
          
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{ flex: 1, padding: 8 }}
          placeholder="Type a message..."
          value={question}
          onChangeText={(text) => setQuestion(text)}
        />
        <Button title="Send" onPress={handleSendMessage} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Chatbot;
```

I tried putting IP address instead of local host, still didnt work.

Comment: can you share the result of fetching data from the endpoint? you can see it on network in inspect mode.

Comment: {answer: "You're welcome! Happy event planning!", id: "2f7f9f9c-97fd-461f-a62c-aed2727040f6",…}
answer
: 
"You're welcome! Happy event planning!"
id
: 
"2f7f9f9c-97fd-461f-a62c-aed2727040f6"
question
: 
"thanks"

Comment: is it same when you use expo app on emulator?

Comment: i have not tried on emulator.. for some reason my emulator doent work at all so i have been using expo only

Comment: first, you must find out where the error message coming from.
in order to check it out, you need to change the message inside of catch from "'Something went wrong'" to "err"

Comment: i am actually not getting error, the problem is only while running on expo the chatbot is not working properly, while i tried it on web it is working perfect...on changing the mssg to err now my chatbot is replying with err only ..its not making any difference